# Having problem with pixelgetcolor within loop and would be open to any suggestion

Tags: autohotkey

This is my code. What i want to do, is this loop to finish what its doing when i find this this color.
I belive the problem is with the cordinates from pixelgetcolor, i have no idea how to put cordinates there. Iv tried with pixelsearch and it wasnt a succes either.Do you have any suggestion what should i do ? The idea is to click non-stop unless this color is on the screen.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen

   Loop ; This loop do non stop, unless the color is on the screen.
          {
            MouseMove, %X%, %Y%
            Click
            sleep,%flick%
            Click
            sleep,%flick1%
            PixelGetColor,Dead_Monster,X,Y,RGB
            if(Dead_Monster = 0x3CC4C4)
            {
              break             ¸
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your variables in `%` for `PixelGetColor` to use the value of those variables. Also, your variables X and Y are never set anywhere...

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen

; initial values?
X := 800
Y := 600

Loop ; This loop do non stop, unless the color is on the screen.
{
    MouseMove, %X%, %Y%

    Click
    sleep,%flick%

    Click
    sleep,%flick1%

    PixelGetColor,Dead_Monster,%X%,%Y%,RGB

    if(Dead_Monster == 0x3CC4C4){
        break
    }

    ; insert line here to update X, Y ?
}
```

If you're looking to search the screen for a pixel, you can do the following:

```
; Modified example from https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm
Dead_Monster := 0x3CC4C4

;Search rectangle
S_Left := 0
S_Top  := 0
S_Bottom := A_ScreenHeight
S_Right := A_ScreenWidth

PixelSearch, Px, Py, %S_Left%, %S_Top%, %S_Bottom%, %S_Right%, %Dead_Monster%, 3, Fast
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, That color was not found in the specified region.
else
    MsgBox, A color within 3 shades of variation was found at X%Px% Y%Py%.
```

However, I don't recommend searching the whole screen area as the search time increases greatly with larger search areas.

Comment: So this : x:= 800 and y:=600, that will scan whole screen ? And why should i then upade x and y ?

Comment: @NeVem I have updated my answer with a `PixelSearch` example.

Comment: @NeVem I hope this helped you! :) If it did please accept and/or up-vote this answer so that it will appear answered for future readers.